# Rickshaw: HoverDetail at incorrect position when using line renderer plus RangeSlider.Preview

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

I have a [Rickshaw Graph](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) with two lines.

I need `Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.Preview` and `Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail`:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById('chart'),
    renderer: 'line',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    offset: 'value',
    series: [
        {
            name: 'foo',
            data: seriesData.shift(),
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
        }, {
            name: 'bar',
            data: seriesData.shift(),
            color: 'rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.4)'
        }
    ]
} );

var slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.Preview({
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('preview')
});

var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
    graph: graph
});

graph.render();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nsams/1jfswzp5/3/

### My Issue

My issue is now that the Hover is shown at an invalid position:

[image: Screenshot]

### What I have found out so far:

- Removing the `RangeSlider.Preview` fixes the problem
- Changing the renderer to 'stack' fixes the problem (Seems like the Hover is at the stack position even when using line renderer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `stack:false` in the `Rickshaw.Graph` constructor:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById('chart'),
    renderer: 'line',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    offset: 'value',
    stack: false,
    series: [
        {
            name: 'foo',
            data: seriesData.shift(),
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
        }, {
            name: 'bar',
            data: seriesData.shift(),
            color: 'rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.4)'
        }
    ]
} );

var slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.Preview({
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('preview')
});

var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
    graph: graph
});

graph.render();
```